# Button and background margin shifted

Tags: android, xml, button, background

I am using android studio, and I try to do some work on UI using some buttons.

I have created a background for some buttons, but when I apply this background on the buttons, the text inside the butons is not centered.

I think the marginof the button remains the same, whereas the applied background creates a smaller square than the marginn of the button. I don't know how to make the margin of the button fit the margin of the square coded in the background xml file.

Here the picture of the problem :

[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6Q2X.png)

Here is the code of the background (bg_rectangle_grey.xml) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:width="@dimen/_34sdp" android:height="@dimen/_34sdp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#ff6c7780" />
            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

And here is the code of the xml file with the button :

```
  <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_15sdp"
            android:style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle">

            <Button
                android:style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_rectangle_grey"
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="M" />
```

I have looked for answers on google but it was never exactly what I am looking for.

If anyone can help.
Thank you in advance

Comment: you show buttonBarButtonStyle and buttonBarButtonStyle code.

Comment: can you post complete xml for this layout

Answer (score 0):

Just use gravity `center` in button

```
       <Button
            android:style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_rectangle_grey"
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="M" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However I have already tried gravity and layout_gravity. It didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Please remove android:width="@dimen/_34sdp" android:height="@dimen/_34sdp" from below code and try again.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:width="@dimen/_34sdp" android:height="@dimen/_34sdp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#ff6c7780" />
            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```